# Adding multiple colors to a network in R

Tags: r, plot

```
library(igraph) 
data <- read.csv("ex.txt", sep=" ", header=F)
```

data contains the edge list

```
graph <- graph.data.frame(data) 
data1 <- read.csv("ex1.txt", sep=" ", header=F)
```

data1 contains the membership IDs of the vertices

```
memberships <- list()  
V(g)$membership <- data1$V2  
V(g) [ membership == 0 ]$color <- "red"   
V(g) [ membership == 1 ]$color <- "blue"  
V(g) [ membership == 2 ]$color <- "green"
V(g) [ membership == 3 ]$color <- "brown"
V(g) [ membership == 4 ]$color <- "orange" 
V(g) [ membership == 5 ]$color <- "Yellow" 
plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.color=V(g)$membership , vertex.size = 2,vertex.label = NA)
```

If you notice, the colors are not as expected, there is black and two variations of blue that is not mentioned.

[image: Plot of the network]

I am unable to find any other method of assigning vertex colors. Please give me some alternatives

Comment: @lukeA Thanks for that. It worked now. I completely misunderstood the plot. Is there any other way of of assigning colors in place of writing the name of the color?

Comment: Sure, please read the documentation `?igraph.plotting`: _"If it is numeric then the current palette is used, see palette. If it is a character vector then it may either contain named colors or RGB specified colors with three or four bytes. All strings starting with ‘#’ are assumed to be RGB color specifications. It is possible to mix named color and RGB colors. Note that tkplot ignores the fourth byte (alpha channel) in the RGB color specification."_. So `palette(topo.colors(12)); plot(g, vertex.color=V(g)$membership)` will also color it.

Answer (score 1):

Map `vertex.color` to `V(g)$color`:

```
library(igraph) 
set.seed(1)
g <- barabasi.game(100, .3)
eb <- edge.betweenness.community(g)
V(g)$membership <- membership(edge.betweenness.community(g))
V(g)$color = "black"
V(g) [ membership == 1 ]$color <- "blue"  
V(g) [ membership == 2 ]$color <- "green"
V(g) [ membership == 3 ]$color <- "brown"
V(g) [ membership == 4 ]$color <- "orange" 
V(g) [ membership == 5 ]$color <- "Yellow" 
V(g) [ membership == 6 ]$color <- "red" 
plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.color=V(g)$color , vertex.size = 2,vertex.label = NA, edge.arrow.size = .3)
```